# Send reviews to google plus and also get reviews from there to site

Tags: review, google-api

I want to know about Google plus review page.

1. How to post reviews on Google plus business page?
2. How to get those reviews from Google plus business page to Magento site and vice a versa?

Note: I am not talking about Google place API reviews.

As I analyze, you can display tweets on your site from twitter.

But is it also possible with Google Plus? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use plugin called [Google+ Feed](http://www.kycosoftware.com/code/googleplus-feed-widget-2) Widget.Hope it helps